# Making zsh autocorrect work with custom git aliases

Tags: git, zsh

I have a custom alias for git that I use with `git df` (it’s basically a shortcut for `git diff`).

However, with git’s zsh autocorrect, everytime I use `git df` in a directory that contains a `db` directory, I get this:

```
% ls
app/ config/ db/ lib/ log/ spec/

% git alias | grep "df"
df = diff

% git df
zsh: correct 'df' to 'db' [nyae]?
```

Is there a way I could make zsh aware of my git aliases so it takes them into account when trying to autocorrect my commands? I want it to detect that `git df` exist and not suggest me `git db` instead.

I don’t want to create a zsh alias (eg. `alias gdf="git diff"`) or use `alias git="nocorrect git"`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe it is easier to disable autocorrection completely: I have not ever seen it correcting something other then file names. And things like `srun command`/`cave resolve package` with having `.command`/`.package` configuration directory are really disgusting. There are too much commands like this to add an alias for each of them.

Comment: At first I thought it was a crazy idea to disable it completely but then I realized that autocorrect was not the same as autocompletion. I like autocompletion, but lately autocorrect has been getting in my way . I disabled it with `unsetopt correct_all` and we’ll see how it goes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You can force zsh to rebuild the autocorrect cache by running the command `hash -rf` or `rehash`.  That fixed my problem when zsh was autocorrecting to the wrong thing.

Comment: This is different: it commands hash containing “command name” - “path to binary” relation as well as “named directory” - “actual path”. Your command won’t fix autocorrections in this case, it may fix only automatic corrections of commands.

Answer (score 3):

Git has an autocorrect feature:

```
git config --global help.autocorrect
```

Will wait 2s before autocorrecting:

```
git config --global help.autocorrect 2
```

I think that if you want to implement this feature in zsh you will have to change the git completion function directly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I find that auto correct gets a bit annoying. So I do in my ~/.zshrc,

```
DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"
```

This disables the auto correct feature. Otherwise, you could do

```
alias git="nocorrect git"
```

but you seem to be averse to that